# AngularJs Routes + Back Button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, angular-routing

I'm using AngularJs with Angular Routes and Phonegap to make my mobile app. It's an ecommerce app so there's a typical category page with filters and sorting and product details page.

Now the issue is whenever I'm on the product details page and click on back it forgets the sorting/filtering/pagination and basically loads the category page afresh.

Also in general how do i stop from hitting the api again when back button is clicked.

Here's how my category controller looks like.

```
app.controller('categoryController', function ($http, $scope, $location, $rootScope, $routeParams, $anchorScroll) {
    loaderShow();
    $scope.filtered = {};
    $scope.minp = 0;
    $scope.maxp = 0;
    $scope.pdts = {};

    $http.get(domain + "/get-category-products/" + $routeParams.url_key + (window.localStorage.getItem('id') != null ? "?userId=" + window.localStorage.getItem('id') : ""), {
        cache: true
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.products = data;
        $scope.pdts = data.data
        $scope.filters = data.filters;
        $scope.$digest;
        loaderHide();
    });

    $scope.load = function (event, url) {
        angular.element(event.target).children("i").addClass("fa fa-spinner fa-pulse");
        $http.get(url, {
            params: {
                'filters': $scope.filtered,
                'minp': $scope.minp,
                'maxp': $scope.maxp,
                'slug': $routeParams.url_key,
                'sort': jQuery("select.orderby").val(),
                'userId': (window.localStorage.getItem('id') != null ? window.localStorage.getItem('id') : "")
            },
            cache: true
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.products = data;
            if (data.data.length > 0) {
                jQuery.each(data.data, function (k, v) {
                    $scope.pdts.push(v);
                });
                angular.element(event.target).children("i").removeClass("fa fa-spinner fa-pulse");
            } else {
                angular.element(event.target).removeAttr("ng-click");
                angular.element(event.target).text("No More Products");
            }

            $scope.$digest;

            loaderHide();

        });
    };

    $scope.filterProds = function (option, parent) {
        if (option) {
            if (!(parent in $scope.filtered))
                $scope.filtered[parent] = [];

            var idx = $scope.filtered[parent].indexOf(option);

            if (idx > -1)
                $scope.filtered[parent].splice(idx, 1);
            else
                $scope.filtered[parent].push(option);

            if ($scope.filtered[parent].length <= 0)
                delete $scope.filtered[parent];
        }
    };

    $scope.applyFilters = function () {
        $scope.minp = jQuery("#min_price").val();
        $scope.maxp = jQuery("#max_price").val();


        $http.get(domain + "/get-filtered-products", {
            params: {
                'filters': $scope.filtered,
                'minp': $scope.minp,
                'maxp': $scope.maxp,
                'slug': $routeParams.url_key,
                'sort': jQuery("select.orderby").val(),
                'userId': (window.localStorage.getItem('id') != null ? window.localStorage.getItem('id') : "")

            }
        }).success(function (response) {
            $scope.products = response;
            $scope.pdts = response.data
            $scope.$digest;
            jQuery(".big-notification.yellow-notification").slideUp();
        });
    }

    $scope.sizeOf = function (obj) {
        return Object.keys(obj).length;
    };

    $scope.showFilters = function () {
        jQuery(".big-notification.yellow-notification").toggle("slideDown");
    }

    $scope.showOptions = function (e) {
        jQuery("#" + e).toggle();
    }

    $scope.$on('ngRepeatFinished', function (ngRepeatFinishedEvent) {
        siteMainFn();
    });


});
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks